# Need details for configuring the digium card

Tags: asterisk

I need to know the appropriate configurations for digium card. what are the things needs to be followed for configuring digium card with PRI. Please can anyone provide me url or document related to digium card configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Outside Connectivity chapter](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596517342/asterisk-OutsideConn.html) of "Asterisk: The Definitive Guide" covers this topic.  The link is to a web version of the book that you can read for free.

If you have trouble, contact [Digium Support](http://www.digium.com/en/supportcenter).  They provide free installation support for Digium hardware.